# Code for Reading AppSettings.json from .Net Core 2.X not working in 5.x

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a code where I read my connection strings from appsettings.json and use in my code as and when required, the code is as follow

1. AppSettings.json

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {

    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=10.17.44.138;Initial Catalog=MTR1;User ID=MTRUser;Password=MTRUser",
    "SAPConnection": "Data Source=10.17.44.138;Initial Catalog=SAP3;User ID=SAPUser;Password=SAP@User123",
    "HRConnection": "Data Source=10.17.44.138;Initial Catalog=HR2;User ID=HRUser;Password=HR@User123",
    "SPSConnection": "Data Source=10.17.44.138;Initial Catalog=SPS1;User ID=SPSUser;Password=SPS@User123",
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

2. Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
    {
        public static string ConnectionString;
        public static string ConnectionStringSAP;
        public static string ConnectionStringHR;
        public static string ConnectionStringSPS;
        public static string ConnectionStringPPS;
        public static string ConnectionStringEQUIP;

        private readonly IConfiguration Config;

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Config = configuration;
            ConnectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            ConnectionStringSAP = configuration.GetConnectionString("SAPConnection");
            ConnectionStringHR = configuration.GetConnectionString("HRConnection");
            ConnectionStringSPS = configuration.GetConnectionString("SPSConnection");
            ConnectionStringPPS = configuration.GetConnectionString("PPSConnection");
            ConnectionStringEQUIP = configuration.GetConnectionString("EQUIPConnection");
        }
}
```

This code was working fine upto ASP.Net core 2.1
but now I am writing new application in VS 2019, i.e. .Net core 5.0
and the same code is not working

I tried running application with this code, but it do not return the connection string

Comment: I am using the connection string from Startup as follow SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Startup.ConnectionString);

Comment: Have your tried to use `Configuration.GetConnectionString(xxxx)` in `ConfigureServices` method? Startup class has it's own Configuration, you don't need to inject it.

Comment: why are you doing like this? why new by injecting `IConfiguration ` to the required class and use like as you have used in your code `configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")`?

Comment: This should work. I don't think your problem is in this part of the code. By the way: don't use .Net 5, it is out of support, use .Net 6 instead

Comment: @XinranShen Yes, I tried Configuration.GetConnectionString(xxxx) its not working

Comment: @JeanotZubler The code is already working fine in .Net core 2.x but not in 5.x

Comment: Do you call `host.UseStartup<Startup>()` in `Program.cs`?

Comment: That `Startup.ConnectionString` is the source of the problem and pretty ugly coding too. The whole point of the Configuration middleware is to *not* put everything into a Singleton class that can be modified by anyone. To use the connection strings either inject an `IConfiguration` to classes and services, or create a class with configuration properties and register it as a service.

Comment: `I am writing new application in VS 2019, i.e. .Net core 5.0` that's a very bad idea because .NET 5 reached End Of Life in May and is now completely unsupported. The current Long Term Support version is .NET 6, supported until 2024

Answer (score -2):

Finally, I found the solution, I change the format of json file as follow and now its working. (Instead of nested ConnectionStrings section, I shift it to as a new block, but surprising that .net 2.x and 5.x understand different formats of json

```
    {
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DefaultConnection": "Data Source=10.7.144.38;Initial Catalog=MTR;User 
         ID=MTRUser;Password=MTRUser",
    "SAPConnection": "Data Source=10.7.144.38;Initial Catalog=SAP;User 
       ID=SAPUser;Password=SAP@User123",
  }
}
```

Comment: They don't use different formats. What's posted here is invalid JSON due to the trailing `{`. Once that's removed, the JSON files are identical